# How to loop through a parsed string in java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of links and they are increasing by one I want to take that xpath of string type and split it where the number is and just change that number by one every time it loops through.

```
String vPath= "/html/body/section/section[2]/a[1]";
//so the number that's changing is in the last bracket 
String[] t = vPath.split("/a");
```

Then I want to use the splitted variable and loop through. so maybe use a for loop. However, I seem to have a problem as to how can I do that. I think it should be like

```
 For (int i=1; i < t(something here); i++{
 then the code of clicking should go here
 }
```

Please help out.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your problem, solution is as follow:

```
         String vPath= "/html/body/section/section[2]/a[1]"; //sample url
         int size = 100; // no of links you want to generate as per your requirement
         String[] chunks = vPath.split("/a");
         String chunk = chunks[0];
         for(int index =1; index <= size;index++){
            System.out.println(chunk+"["+index+"]"); // printing generated urls
            //code of clicking...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If working with a recent JDK (1.5+), then use:

```
for (String chunk: vPath.split("/a")) {
    System.out.println(chunk);
    // and anything else with chunk here...
}
```

But, before, please get a good Java book and study arrays and collections.